# How to add a context menu to existing "File" menu in Eclipse Plugin development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse main menu  how to contribute to an existing Main Menu  for ex need to create a context menu under  Main menu "File"  . What is the location URI "File"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location URI for the file menu is `menu:file`.

See `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` for information about the different sections and IDs...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to add submenu to File menu:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            id="com.my.plugin.actionSet"
            label="My ActionSet"
            visible="true">
         <menu
               id="mymenu"
               label="My Menu"
               path="file/fileEnd">
            <groupMarker
                  name="start">
            </groupMarker>
            <separator
                  name="additions">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               class="com.my.plugin.ActionClass"
               id="com.myplugin.action"
               label="Action"
               menubarPath="file/mymenu/start"
               style="push">
         </action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>
```

Constants for positioning MyMenu within File menu could be found at `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchActionConstants`

Cheers,
Max